# How add an image to an existing pdf file from a location and should save back to same location?

Tags: java, image, pdf, image-processing, jpeg

How add an image to an existing pdf file from a location,
 and should save back to same location, I have used following code but it generates a new pdf with existing jpeg. But how to deal with existing pdf file and save resultant pdf image?

```
 import java.io.*;
 import com.lowagie.text.*;
 import com.lowagie.text.pdf.*;

 public class imagesPDF
 {
 public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception
 {
   Document document=new Document();
   PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("imagesPDF.pdf"));
   document.open();
   Image image = Image.getInstance ("devi.jpg");
   document.add(new Paragraph("textdata"));
   document.add(image);
   document.close();
 }
 }
```

Comment: <DWS>The code is probably failing because of the mention of `Roseindia`.</DWS>  Is that where you sourced the code?

Comment: that works fine..but generating new pdf from jpeg...i need to add jpeg image to existing pdf

Comment: To manipulate an existing PDF with iText use a PdfStamper, not a plain PdfWriter. BTW, as your sample is quite iText centric and doesn't do any actual image-processing, I would replace the image-processing tag by an itext tag.